# How to delete top N rows in a dataset in .net framework 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, dataset

I need to  delete the first four rows in a DataSet in my application.  Is there a way to do it in the code behind file?

Comment: Try MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].Delete();

Comment: Post your code and what you have tried.....

Answer (score 1):

```
dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(n).Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydatatable = mydataset.Tables[0].Rows
                  .Cast<System.Data.DataRow>()
                  .OrderBy(x => x["Numbers"]).Skip(1).CopyToDataTable();
```

skip() function will skip that row and copy remaining rows to target datatable , so we can use it as delete

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming your DataSet is declared as "ds":

```
int x = 0;
int n = 4;//n being your number of rows to delete
            do
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[x].Delete();
                x++;
            } while (x < n);
```

Edit: Updated the "error" in my logic... >.< I was saying something like x = n, which won't delete the first four rows in a dataset.